# screen command in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, jobs, gnu-screen, hpc

I have logged onto the HPC, and then used : `screen -list`
It showed the following.

```
 > There are screens on:
    >   40032.pts-45.willow (16/06/17 13:59:42) (Detached)
    >   37414.pts-45.willow (15/06/17 15:01:30) (Detached)
    >   37002.pts-45.willow (15/06/17 14:51:18) (Attached)
```

I don't understand why 37002 showed attached. However, if I try to use: `screen -r 37002`

```
There is a screen on:
    37002.pts-45.willow (15/06/17 14:51:18) (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed matching 37002.
```

From my understanding, there is no screen for 37002.

Comment: You could also try running: screen -d -r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to tmux ;) Seriously. I think that tmux is way better for keeping stuff alive.

https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki

In your case, it looks like you have started screen inside screen. In that case you can get this kind of result:

```
┌[michalo@pi]
└[~] screen -list
There are screens on:
    770.ttys000.pi  (Detached)
    831.ttys004.pi  (Attached)
2 Sockets in /var/folders/hd/fsr88b711nq969xyv329d68c0000gn/T/.screen.

┌[michalo@pi]
└[~] screen -r 831
There is a screen on:
    831.ttys004.pi  (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed matching 831.
```

To reproduce this one, simply do

```
screen
screen
```

And then, from another terminal, try to log into attached session. It should give you error as you stated. To be honest, I don't know whether this is a bug or a feature ;)